# How do I add the data stored in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

How can i add the data entered into the array by the prompt as its being entered then divide it by the number of array size which is 4? The only thing i really need help with is adding up the data entered and dividing it to get the average to display.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

// declare variables and constants
   var SIZE = 4   // array size
   var gradeArray // array variable
   var gradeAvg  // grade average variable
   var avgCalc = parseFloat(avgCalc); // variable used to store avg grade
   var letGrad = "" // variable used to store Letter Grade
   var userInput  // variable used for while function
   var index  // loop variable
   var BR = "<br></br>" // page break
   var ES = ""  // empty string
   var semi = ":"
// Create Array
   gradeArray = new Array(SIZE);   
}

// Create Loop structure for user grade input and ask if input is correct
   while (userInput != "Y") {
   for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {  
      gradeArray[index] = prompt("Enter your grades # " + (index + 1) + ":" + ES);
}

// Create display function for loop structure, Displays user input of grades

   document.write("Grades Entered:" + BR);
   for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {   
      document.write("The grades you entered are: ");
      document.write(gradeArray[index] + BR);
}
   userInput = prompt("Are the these grades correct? (Y/N)");   
   if (userInput == "Y") {
     document.write("Thank you!" + BR);
}
}
// Create selection structure. This structure gives the average a letter grade
   if (avgCalc >= 90) {
     letGrad = "A";
}
   else if (avgCalc >= 80) {
     letGrad = "B";
}
   else if (avgCalc >= 70) {
     letGrad = "C";
}
   else if (avgCalc >= 60) {
     letgrad = "D";
}
   else if (avgCalc < 60) {
     letGrad = "F";

}

// Display results -- display's results
   document.write("Your average is: " + avgCalc + semi + letGrad + BR);
   document.write("Thank you for using Average Calculator!");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you include all the code, right now you are missing a brace and we don't know where gradeArray is created.

Comment: You don't need to store your values in an array if all you're doing is working out the average.

Comment: Im not just working out the average. in that case id just take the input into separate variables and then use a function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Array `reduce()` method. It takes a accumulator and a value, sums them and stores into your accumulator. Like this:

```
var gradeSum = gradeArray.reduce(function(total, n){ 
  return total + n
});
```

This will give you the sum of all grades stored in your array.
The you only need to divide it like that

```
var med = gradeSum/gradeSum.length
```

Now your `med` var will have the value that you want!

Take a further look on Array reduce method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

I got it! like i knew there was a simpler way. I am an amateur programmer. you guys are alot more advanced than me so your examples(that are simple to you) is kind of advanced to me.

```
// Welcome user
   document.write("Welcome to Grade Average Calculator" + BR);
// Create Array
   gradeArray = new Array(SIZE);   

// Create Loop structure for user grade input and ask if input is correct
   while (userInput != "Y") {
   for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) { 
      gradeArray[index] = prompt("Enter your grades # " + (index + 1) + ":" + ES);
      gradeSum = +gradeArray[0] + +gradeArray[1] + +gradeArray[2] + +gradeArray[3];
      avgCalc = gradeSum / 4;
}
```